# Richfaces : How to iterate through UITreeModelRecursiveAdaptor and its nodes in BackingBean?

Tags: treeview, richfaces, jsf-2.2

The question is in the title .

I don't understand what getNodes() return. If it was a list, i see how to go through but i don't know what to do the Object...
I'd like to get the name of my node parsing the Dom with UIComponent Tree.

Look doc [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.5.Final/javadoc/richfaces-components-ui/).

Answer (score 0):

It returns either a `List` (or something that is `Iterable`) or a `Map`.